# trying to pass integer to different class

Tags: android, integer

So far I have been able to successfully pass a string using this method, however it seems to not be working when I try to pass an integer.

Class that is setting the integer has the following:

***My Helper***

```
    public int getHoles() {
    return setHoles;
}
```

***My Button***

```
case R.id.buttonSetHoles:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final CharSequence[] items = {"18", "9"};
        builder.setTitle("Set Holes");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (items[item] == "9"){
                    int setHoles = 9;
                }
                else if (items[item] == "18"){
                    int setHoles = 18;
                }
                return;
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
        return;
```

***Class that needs the data***

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String name1 = EasyPar.helper.getNames(); <--- works fine for this one
    int setHoles = EasyPar.helper.getHoles();
}
```

Whenever I try to use the value, it just comes up with nothing.  If i try to:

```
textHoleNumber.setText(String.valueOf(setHoles));
```

it just displays 0

the only way I can get it to work is if i just set the value upfront as setHoles = 18; or so.

I tried to move the "helper" to the end of the class but that didnt work.  I am thinking that the ***My Button*** is not correctly setting the setHoles value ***or*** I am not correctly passing the value outside of the "case R.id.buttonLetsGo" (if i put setHoles = 10; inside of public int getHoles() {
        return setHoles;
    } then it works no problem so its definitely calling that getHoles.

If theres any more data i can provide please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be a scoping problem:

```
            if (items[item] == "9"){
                int setHoles = 9;
            }
            else if (items[item] == "18"){
                int setHoles = 18;
            }
```

You're declaring new "setHoles" integers here, and they only exist for one line. Any other variable named "setHoles" from elsewhere in your code is being hidden by these new ones. (Your compiler should be giving you a warning about this, too.)

I hope that helps!

Comment: so how would I go about keeping them for more than just one line, and using them somewhere else?

Comment: By using "int setHoles = 18;" instead of "setHoles = 18;", what you're doing is creating a new variable that happens to have the name "setHoles" and you are assigning the value of 18 to it. If you simply assign 18 to the variable with "setHoles = 18;", rather than declaring a new variable with "int setHoles = 18;", it should work well.

The Wikipedia article on [scope](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Scoping) should explain the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The problem might lie in the fact that int is a primitive and String is an object. Try using the Integer wrapper class to pass the value and see what happens.

like this

```
int q = 35;
Integer i = new Integer(q);
```

Then pass the i value using your method. Hope this helps!

Comment: That won't solve your problem. Essentially you're not actually assigning a value to "setHoles" because you're assigning a value to newly created "setHoles" variables.